# Does it make sense computing the mean value of a set of MSE values?

Tags: mean, image-processing, mse

First of all, thank you for your attention. One of my class projects asked me to quantify the asymmetry of 3 classes of moles, given a dataset. In order to do that, I estimated the MSE between a 2D version of the mole and its 2D flipped version. The professor requires the statistical properties of the asymmetry (standard deviation and mean value). Since computing the standard deviation of a set of MSE values didn't seem right to me, I used the RMSE the std, but I don't know what to do with the mean. I quantified the asymmetry taking the MSE value in percentage. Taking the mean of those values for each class is something I can do or is it conceptually wrong?

Comment: By calculating the standard deviation, you have to calculate the mean.

Comment: maybe I wasn't clear. My question is "I am using the MSE values to estimate the asymmetry of a set of moles. If I compute the standard deviation, so also the mean, over all the MSE values I have, is this computation conceptually wrong?"

Comment: How does the MSE even estimate asymmetry?

Comment: I read about it here. I think that the higher is the difference between the image and its flipped version, the higher will be the MSE https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/331162-how-do-i-quantify-the-symmetry-of-an-image